# Javascript pause in WinRT for animation

Tags: javascript, windows-8, windows-runtime

I want to pause execution in javascript so that I can animate the appearance of text on the screen.  My code is currently this:

```
function AnimateWord(word) {
    for (var i = 0; i <= word.length; i++) {
        myTest.textContent += word.charAt(i);
        // need to pause here and then continue
    }
}
```

I've done some research and the preferred method to do this in javascript seems to be `setTimeout`, although I can't really see how that would work in this case without creating a recursive loop (which just doesn't seem like the right solution to me).

Is there a way around this, or am I stuck with `setTimeout` and a recursive loop?

EDIT:

Based on some additional tests, I've tried using the `Promise.timeout`:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= word.length; i++) {
    WinJS.Promise.timeout(1000).then(TypeLetter(word.charAt(i)));
}

function TypeLetter(letter) {
    myTest.textContent += letter;
}
```

But this doesn't seem to actually pause.  In fact, it seems to completely ignore the timeout.  I've also tried:

```
setTimeout(TypeLetter(word.charAt(i)), 1000);
```

With basically the same results.  [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/br229729.aspx) seems to imply that it should wait and then execute the task.  I'm quite new to WinJS, but am equating a promise to an `await` keyword in C#.

Comment: Just FYI, the loop over `WinJS.Promise.timeout(1000).then(...);` creates a bunch of promises at once which all execute one second after the loop completes.

Comment: Also, `setTimeout(TypeLetter(word.charAt(i)), 1000);` isn't right unless `TypeLetter` returns a function. Here, `TypeLetter` executes immediately, and the result of `TypeLetter` gets passed as the first argument to `setTimeout`. Instead, you might wrap your call inside an anonymous function: `setTimeout(function() { ... }, 1000);`

Comment: You are calling `TypeLetter` too soon. You mean `WinJS.Promise.timeout(1000).then(TypeLetter.bind(null, word.charAt(i)))` or `setTimeout(TypeLetter.bind(null, word.charAt(i)), 1000)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var i = 0;
var str = "plz send teh codez";
var intervalId = setInterval(function(){
    myTest.textContent += str.charAt(i);
    if (++i >= str.length)
        clearInterval(intervalId);
}, 1000);
```

#### demo http://jsfiddle.net/qxfVu/1/

Answer (score 2):

setTimeout/setIngerval/requestAnimationFrame are pretty much your only choices. I wouldn't call them recursive perse - while you do call your same function over & over. The calls tack is completely independent.

What kind of animation are you really trying to create? It may be better to create a span for each character, have them hidden, and then fade/translate the, in using CSS animations.

Comment: Using CSS wouldn't work, as what is shown will potentially be removed during the display process.  The effect I'm trying to create is a little like you see on films where a code or password is being uncovered - so you'll see it run through letters and numbers until it finds the right one and displays that.

Comment: I'm not sure you should rule out CSS. In JavaScript you can not only manipulate the classes on your elements which effectively applies or unapplies (new word!) animations, but you can also manipulate style rules that are in effect.

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you are looking for:

```
var array1 = [];
function AnimateWord(word) {
    var test = $('#test');            
    for (var i = 0; i <= word.length; i++) {
        array1.push(word.charAt(i));
        test.delay(100).queue(function() {
            this.innerHTML += array1[0];
            array1.splice(0, 1);
            $(this).dequeue();
        });
    }
}
```

please see fiddle link as well: http://jsfiddle.net/7Ea9u/